# When I deploy Nginx Ingress K8s Controller, My pods are in CrashBackLoopOff stage

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress

I am new to k8s, Its strange that my pods are always in CrashLoopBackOff state, Although I am following the instruction from Official guide.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

State: Waiting
Reason: CrashLoopBackOff
Last State: Terminated
Reason: Error
Exit Code: 255

Can anyone elaborate why its happening.
Thank you.

Comment: Describing the pod / retrieving events in the namespace will give a clue why that pod is having "CrashLoopBackOff" status

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: After checking with describe mypod, it says
 State:          Waiting
 Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
 Last State:     Terminated
 Reason:       Error
 Exit Code:    255

Comment: @Community, if you see the picture may be you get something.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Right now the question pretty much only consists of a link to an image; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], with all required information directly in the question and as plain text?

Comment: @DavidMaze can you see now. Please!!

Answer (score 0):

The "error" you are receiving is actually an event. The status field contains the latest event in the chain which in your case states that K8s is refusing to keep restarting your pod due to an infinite loop of crash-restart operations.

In order to identify your root cause for why the pod is crashing you can resort to all events (in case your pod is crashing before the container is spun up) or logs (when your pod crashes due to the container within)

To list events:
Right after spinning up a new pod - run `watch "kubectl describe pod my-pod-zl6m6 | grep -A20 Events"`
Keep monitoring events and you might find common issues such as K8s being unable to pull image.

For logs:
Run `kubectl logs --tail=100 -f my-pod-zl6m6` right after spinning up the pod.
Or if the pod crashes too quickly and you can't get the logs command running in time - `kubectl logs --previous my-pod-zl6m6`